# convert Object and wrap to another with recursive field in java

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, java-stream

For some reasons, I need a new object to wrap the data I get from other API.

The problem I faced was that no idea to handle recursive field from the original object.

Here is the sample code:

```
//original object
public class Resource{
    private String name;
    private String content;
    private Integer type;
    private List<Resource> children = new LinkedList();
    public void addChildrenResource(Resource children) {
        this.children.add(children);
    }
    //getters&setters...
}
```

---

```
//the object try to convert
public class Menu{
    private String name;
    private String url;
    private Integer type;
    private List<Menu> subMenu = new LinkedList();
    public void addChildrenResource(Menu subMenu) {
        this.children.add(subMenu);
    }
    //getters&setters...
}
```

---

The implementation I did that I have no idea to do with recursive field...
 Here is my code..

```
List<Resource> resources = rpcService.getResources();

//Here I can't handle the subMenu or children part..
List<Menu> menus = resources.stream().map(r -> new Menu(r.getName(), 
r.getContent(), r.getType())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

The recursion may be many layers, so how can I convert it with recursive field?

Note: The `Resource` class is from another module so I can't change that, for naming problem I must convert it.
We don't have to solve it by `Stream()`, just find a way to figure it out.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to copy the class like that? You could just use inheritance on your Resource class and not copy it if that´s an option. While you might not be able to change the class itself you can most deffinitely inherit from it and overwrite it´s behaviour where needed.

Comment: Is it really recursive?  Or do you mean deeply nested?

Comment: well, I mean deeply nested..

Answer (score 8):

You need make a method and call this method recursively:

```
public static List<Menu> convert(List<Resource> resources) {
    return resources == null ? null :
            resources.stream()
                    .map(r -> new Menu(r.getName(), r.getContent(), r.getType(), convert(r.getChildren)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```